# AURA Issue: Apex method is firing but no data returned in CMP

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, community

Hello Salesforce Friends!

Below is a basic button, that fires an apex method to return a list of records. This is on a community page. I can see in the console that the button is firing and getting an empty result. In the Apex Debugs, I can see that the apex method is also firing, but for some reason the data is not reaching the component. Any help, would be greatly appreciated as this is an emergency situation for our community.
Thanks!

### HTML

```
<lightning:button label="MY Button" onclick="{!c.myFunction}"></lightning:button>
```

### Controller.js

```
"myFunction" : function(component, helper){
        component.set("v.isWorking", true);
        let action = component.get("c.getCommunityContent");
        // action.setParams({"recName" : "Blackstone: Statement of Faith"});
        action.setCallback(this, function (response) {
            let state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
               
                        // component.set('v.CMSResult', data[0]);    
                        console.log('MY DATA'); 
                        console.log(response.getReturnValue()); 
                        
                                 
            } else  {
                console.log('NO DATA');
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response.getError()));
                
            }
            
            component.set("v.isWorking", false);
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
```

### APEX

```
  @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Dynamic_Community_Data__c> getCommunityContent(){
        System.debug('IM IN');
        try {
            List<Dynamic_Community_Data__c> content = [
                SELECT 
                    Id,
                    Name, 
                    Content_Title__c, 
                    Content_Body__c, 
                    Target_Experience_Site__c 
                FROM Dynamic_Community_Data__c 
                WHERE ID = 'hardcodedId'
                LIMIT 1
            ];
            return content;  
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug(e.getMessage());
            throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
           
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you get the 'NO DATA' error or is just the result of 'getReturnValue()' empty? Have you tried debugging what's returned by your query in the controller? Are you sure there are no permissions issue? I'd try temporarily changing the class to 'without sharing' and see if it changes anything.

Comment: Using without sharing did the trick. Tried it just before you messaged. just havent had a chance to update the post with an answer.